# getting this error : illegal attempt to dereference collection [{synthetic-alias}{non-qualified-property-ref}gcmUsers]

Tags: hibernate, hql

i have 2 table  GcmUser  and   GroupName in many to many  relation in hibernate .

my query is :

```
from GcmUser
where clientName='admin'
and  id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM GroupName
    WHERE id =
        (
            SELECT id
            FROM GroupName
            WHERE groupName = 'Multy'
            AND gcmUsers.userName ='niraj'
        )
)
order by createdDateTime asc
```

and I got the error: `illegal attempt to dereference collection [{synthetic-alias}{non-qualified-property-ref}gcmUsers] with element property reference [userName]`

full stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [{synthetic-alias}{non-qualified-property-ref}gcmUsers] with element property reference [userName] [select count(*) as totalcount  from com.bonrix.gcm.demo.model.GcmUser where clientName='admin'and  id IN(SELECT id FROM com.bonrix.gcm.demo.model.GroupName WHERE id =(SELECT id FROM com.bonrix.gcm.demo.model.GroupName WHERE groupName = 'Multy' AND gcmUsers.userName ='gadia'))]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode$1.buildIllegalCollectionDereferenceException(DotNode.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.checkLhsIsNotCollection(DotNode.java:550)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode.resolve(FromReferenceNode.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:881)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4297)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3769)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1947)
```

i can not understand the meaning of the error .and why it comes?????

Comment: What is `gcmUsers.userName`?

Comment: private Set<GcmUser> gcmUsers = new HashSet<GcmUser>(0); it's in GroupName and String userName is in GcmUser and i have many to many relationship.

Comment: IMHO That's why you're getting this exception. You need to first make join on `gcmUsers` & then use `gcmUsers.userName`.

Comment: The Hibernate docs state that HQL doesn't need explicit joins - see '[14.4 Forms of join syntax](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms) - the only difference between Niraj's syntax and the docs appears to be that the docs use (equiv to) `GroupName.cmUsers.userName` (i.e. name at start), but that doesn't appear to help...

Comment: Using the example HQL, both with/without alias, gives errors of either `Unable to resolve path [GroupName.gcmUsers], unexpected token [GroupName]` or `illegal attempt to dereference collection [groupName0_.id.gcmUsers] with element property reference [userName]` - for the code I'm dealing with at least (I subbed the column names for consistency).

Comment: And yet, using an explicit join as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327122/hibernate-exception-illegal-attempt-to-dereference-a-collection/6327231#6327231) does appear to work - the alias for Project is apparently required (but the inv one seems to be optional.